# Android Activity : weird activities flow

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-lifecycle

I'm investigating a mysterious crash in my Android app based on the logs sent from users's devices. 
So basically there're 2 activities A and B. Users go from activity A to activity B by clicking a button in activity A. 
Here're the logs i received :

```
0 | 19:10:47:758 | D/CrashlyticsCore A onCreate()  
1 | 19:10:47:794 | D/CrashlyticsCore A onStart()   
2 | 19:10:47:797 | D/CrashlyticsCore A onResume()   
3 | 19:11:24:712 | D/CrashlyticsCore A onPause()  
4 | 19:11:24:732 | D/CrashlyticsCore B onCreate()    
5 | 19:11:25:314 | D/CrashlyticsCore B onStart()     
6 | 19:11:25:318 | D/CrashlyticsCore B onResume()     
7 | 19:11:25:817 | D/CrashlyticsCore A onStop()    
8 | 19:12:02:090 | D/CrashlyticsCore B onPause()   
9 | 19:12:02:107 | D/CrashlyticsCore A onRestart()   
10 | 19:12:02:108 | D/CrashlyticsCore A onStart()    
11 | 19:12:02:111 | D/CrashlyticsCore A onResume()    
12 | 19:12:02:451 | D/CrashlyticsCore B onStop()  
13 | 19:12:02:463 | D/CrashlyticsCore B onDestroy()  
14 | 19:12:03:071 | D/CrashlyticsCore A onPause()   
15 | 19:12:03:117 | D/CrashlyticsCore B onCreate()
```

The left columns are line numbers and timestamps. So this user stayed in screen B for a while, and then clicked back (as seen in line number 8). From line number 8 to line number 15, it seems like there's no user interaction here because it lasted only 1 second. But somehow, activity B onCreate() is called again (last line)

So in what way could this happen ?

Comment: please as per my knowledge here your flow is 1.) come into Activity A 2.) press button on activity A 3.) come to Activity B 4.) press back button from Activity B. 5.) again press button on Activity A. Right?

Comment: I hope that's the case, but don't you think it's too fast ?

Comment: just let me tell if you press back button or not? if you press then its going on perfect way.

Comment: This is user, not me. So i don't know if they pressed Back, but it's likely so.

Answer (score 0):

In line 13 activity B is destroyed so creating it in line 15 is not unusual. It could be destroyed if android runtime is low on resources.